# "Is my site down?" Howto

Tags: ruby, web

What's the best way to create a "Is my site down?" in Ruby? How should I do it to check it using HTTP(s) and Ping?

Thanks.

Comment: could just use existing services for that if the open web scenario applies: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/stackoverflow.com

Comment: @BrokenGlass, the same idea )

Comment: @BrokenGlass: The site doesn't seem to return reliable results. It returned: "It's not just you! http://google.com looks down from here." while I asked for the status for google.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically just use a http library to see if you can get (actually, HEADing would be better) the page they're pointing to. If you get a response then the server is up, otherwise (it doesn't respond or times out) it is down and you alert the user accordingly.

This isn't the cleanest way of doing it, but basically:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def isUp( url )
    uri = URI.parse( url )

    begin
        Timeout::timeout(5) {
            Net::HTTP.start( uri.host, uri.port ) { |http|
                 http.head( uri.path )
            }
        }
    rescue Timeout::Error
        return false
    end

    return true 
end
```

You can probably get it to not wait for the timeout, and/or increase the timeout to avoid the timeout to avoid false positive, but this is a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

(cheat)

```
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'
site = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
open("http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/#{URI.parse(site).host}"){|f|f.read}["It's not just you!"]
```